# How can i use variables inside a connectionString inside app.confg?

Tags: c#

I want to do this in my `app.confg`.

```
<configuration>
    <appSetting>
        <add key="user" value="root"/>
        <add key="pass" value="root"/>
    </appSetting>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="mysql" 
             connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username={user}; password={pass};" 
             providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I get the value of `mysql`using

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString
```

it returns

```
datasource=localhost; port=3306; username={user}; password={pass};
```

and my objective is to get this returned:

```
datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And why would you want to do this, if I may ask? It is a **configuration** file. It's purpose is to have configuration in it. If you are concerned about storing credentials, the section can be encrypted.

Comment: I mean, you can do this.  But you'll have to perform the interpolation yourself.  But why would you want to do this?

Comment: Just read it and manipulate it as you want as a string then use it

Comment: Even better, use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` and modify the properties so you don't have to do string manipulation yourself.

Comment: But it is possible to do it in this way?

Comment: No, the standard .NET config system doesn't have any feature to allow "parameters" or "variables" to be used

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz `But it is possible to do it in this way?`  Read the first two sentences of my previous comment very carefully.  Then read the last one.  It makes no sense to do this.

Comment: Apart from the lack of research and attempt, I honestly don't think this is necessarily a bad question. This seems like a somewhat reasonable assumption to make about the app.config if you aren't all that familiar with them. It's just not an appropriate approach (as mentioned in some of the previous comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your connection string to this:

```
<add name="mysql" 
         connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username={0}; password={1};" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Then in your C# code you can use `string.Format` method to replace the values:

```
string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString, "root", "root");
```

> This kind of solution is not recommended you should keep all your connection string in the configuration file. If you have multiple connection strings for different operation or user. You should create multiple connection strings in your configuration file. Each connection will have a different name, and you will call the connection by it's name. Keep user and password in your CS code is very very very very bad.

In this case your config file will be like this:

```
    <configuration>
        <appSetting>
            <add key="user" value="root"/>
            <add key="pass" value="root"/>
        </appSetting>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="admin" 
                 connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=adimn; password=aVeryBigComplexPassword;" 
                 providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
            <add name="user" 
                 connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=OnlyReader; password=otherVeryBigComplexPassword;" 
                 providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Then in your code you can get the connection string easily like this:

```
var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["admin"].ConnectionString;
```

Or

```
var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["user"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: In last case you dont use the variables user and pass in the connectionString and my question it is this possible

Comment: It is possible, as I show in the first example. The second one is just a better way to work with multiple connection strings

Answer (score 1):

You could load the configuration string then do a string.Replace on it.

Something like this:

```
String.Replace(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString,"{user}","my value");
```